# Error entity is not mapped en Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Al arrancar el tomcat , al tener añadir en mi clase el findByDni, me el error: personas is not mapped. Esta es la clase JpaRepository

```
public interface IRepositorioPersonas extends JpaRepository<PersonasDTO, Integer>{

  @Query("FROM personas where dni = ?1")
  List<PersonasDTO> findByDNI(String dni);

}
```

Esta mi clase: PersonasDTO

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "datpersonas")
@Table(name="personas")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonasDTO implements Serializable{

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="id")
 int id;
 @Column(name="dni")
 String dni;
 @Column(name="nombre")
 String nombre;
 @Column(name="apellido1")
 String apellido1;
 @Column(name="apellido2")
 String apellido2;
 @Column(name="telefono")
 String telefono;
 @Column(name="email")
 String email;}
```

¿Alguna idea para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te puedo señalar dos cosas:

**1-** Para consultas tan sencillas como la que necesitas puedes usar [*query methods*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) (como parece ser que has intentado viendo el nombre del método que definiste `findByDNI(...)`). Ahora bien, no estoy seguro de que funcione poniendo DNI (así todo en mayúsculas), quizá lo correcto debería ser `findByDni(...)`.

**2-** En las consultas JPQL (que es el tipo de consulta que se usan con la anotación `@Query` cuando no la marcas como `native`) debes usar el nombre de la entidad en vez del nombre de la tabla, por lo que la consulta correcta sería: `FROM PersonasDTO p WHERE p.dni = ?1`.

Pero como te comenté, si usas la variante primera no es necesaria la anotación `@Query`.

Comment: me ha funcionado muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Me allegro!! Saludos